# Class App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController does not exist

Tags: laravel-5, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am Having the issue of not getting token in postman as well as the following problem

> ReflectionException 
>   …\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php790
>   user controller does not exist

**my route file;**

```
Route::post('login', 'API\UserController@login'); 
Route::post('register', 'API\UserController@register'); 
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
   Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details'); 
});
```

**My controller file;**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;   
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use App\User; 
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
 use Validator; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class UserController extends Controller {
        //
        public $successStatus = 200;
        /** 
         * login api 
         * 
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
         */ 
        public function login(){ 
            if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
                $user = Auth::user(); 
                $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
                return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
            } 
            else{ 
                return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
            } 
        }
        /** 
         * Register api 
         * 
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
         */ 
        public function register(Request $request) 
        { 
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
                'name' => 'required', 
                'email' => 'required|email', 
                'password' => 'required', 
                'c_password' => 'required|same:password', 
            ]); if ($validator->fails()) { 
                return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
            } $input = $request->all(); 
            $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']); 
            $user = User::create($input); 
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
            $success['name'] =  $user->name; return response()->json(['success'=>$success], $this-> successStatus); 
        } 
       /** 
         * details api 
         * 
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
         */ 
        public function details() 
        { 
            $user = Auth::user(); 
            return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this-> successStatus); 
        }  
}
```

How can I Solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your controller path is `/App/Http/Controllers/API`, you need to adjust it's namespace :

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
```

If your controller path is `/App/Http/Controllers`, you need to adjust your routes:

```php
Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
```

Comment: Please note that in the code you provided, the routes point to "App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController" but that your controller is defined into the "App\Http\Controllers" namespace :-)

Answer (score 1):

simply just write folder extension in namespace

for example in your case

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;`

And in route you just write

```php
Route::post('register','api\UserController@register');
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you are not calling the right middleware on the user route that directs to that controller. You would have to create a user middleware.

You can do this by navigating to your App\Http\Middleware and add the user middleware with the name UserMiddleware.php and some code to it.

Firstly, you would need to import the following files;

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

- Then you create a class called; `class UserMiddleware`
- Add a handle function to it like so; `public function handle($request, Closure $next)`
- Inside this function include the following code;

  ```
  if (Auth::user()->usertype == 'user')
  {
      return $next($request);
  }
  ```

Next up, head over to you App\Http\Kernel.php and add the following code at the bottom of the ***protected $routeMiddleware*** section;

```
        'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserMiddleware::class,
```

Then go over to your route (API) and include this predefined user middleware to your URLs.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'user'], function () {

   Route::post('login', 'API\UserController@login'); 
   Route::post('register', 'API\UserController@register');
   Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details'); 

});
```

});

For this to work you would need to have a `usertype` field in your users table that is set to `user` by default. Your usertype column should look like this;

```
    $table->string('usertype')->nullable()->default('user');
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Copy the existing functions of your controller and delete it.

**2**. Recreate your controller but  this time specifying the location of were you want to place it, in the Controllers directory. e.g.

php artisan make:controller NameOfYourSubFolder\YourControllersName

**3**. Paste you functions.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has web route and API route, with different namespace/path configuration, where the issue such as  "Class App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController does not exist" comes from.

- Web route:

in controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\Application;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
```

in web.php route file:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

- API route:

in controller:
the namespace should be App\Http\Controllers\API if you put your API controllers in \API path.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CartController extends Controller
{
```

in api.php route file, add API\ to the controller path.

```
Route::get('/carts', 'API\CartController@index');
```